Не работает коллизия с обьектами
        collide = sprite.spritecollide(impostor, player, False, False)
        if collide:
            player.speed = 0

Именно здесь мне выдает ошибку

TypeError: 'Player' object is not iterable

это столкновение двух спрайтов. Возможно вторым параметром должна быть группа, но зачем она мне если у меня только два спрайта во всей игре?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488088/how-do-i-detect-the-collision-of-two-sprites-using-pygame

    collide = sprite.collide_rect(impostor, player)
    if collide:
        player.speed = 0


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
